# Can a PHP callback accept its parameter(s) by reference?

Tags: php, arrays, reference, callback, array-filter

I've tested the following and it works on both PHP 5.2 and 5.3, however, it's not documented anywhere as far as I can see so I'm evaluating its use.

I have a function in a class called isValid, this checks a hash to see if the given value is in the set of allowed values. There are some values that *are* valid, but deprecated; I'd like my isValid function to update the passed in value to the current one and return true.

That's fine for when I call it myself, however, I'd like to use this method when used as a callback for array_filter too.

Here's a test case, which as expected results in an array with the values 2,3,4,5,6.

```
<?php
$test = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
echo print_r(array_filter($test, 'maptest'), true);

function maptest(&$value)
{
$value ++;
return true;
}
```

So StackOverflow: is this allowed, or is it undocumented functionality that may disappear/stop working/cause errors in the future?

Comment: Who says it's undocumented? A callback is a regular function just like any other.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you doing `echo print_r($var, true);` instead of just `print_r($var)`?

Comment: Hi blockhead - I couldn't find it documented that it's explicitly supported, the documentation states it isn't for call_user_function for instance.



NullUserException - just force of habit from putting the output of a print_r between <div> tags in a single line.

Comment: @NullUserException, this is interesting because like he is using echo print_r(); if you don't put true it echoes a 1 after array, but if you remove besides this true also echo its working the same as with echo and true, can somebody explain this?

Comment: @Vadim `print_r()` takes an optional boolean parameter, if it's true it returns the output instead of printing it (default)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed.

In this respect, there's nothing special about calling functions through callbacks.

However, your specific example does not illustrate one difficulty. Consider:

```
function inc(&$i) { $i++; }
$n = 0;
// Warning:  Parameter 1 to inc() expected to be a reference, value given:
call_user_func('inc', $n);
```

The problem is that you're passing `$n` to `call_user_func` and `call_user_func` doesn't accept values by reference. So by the time `inc` is called, it won't receive a reference. This isn't a problem with `array_filter` because it traverses the array directly and can directly pass the variables in the array to the callback function.

You *could* use call-time pass-by-reference, but this is deprecated and removed from trunk:

```
function inc(&$i) { $i++; }
$n = 0;
// Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
call_user_func('inc', &$n);
```

So the best option is to use `call_user_func_array` instead:

```
function inc(&$i) { $i++; }
$n = 0;
call_user_func_array('inc', array(&$n));
```

This function will pass-by-reference the elements that have the `is_ref` flag set and will pass-by-value the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

[Except when explicitly noted](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), I'd say this is fine and acceptable. [A callback can be any built-in or user-defined function](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).